# Newest Quickblox SDK for Android: Get nearby locations does not work

Tags: android, geolocation, android-location, quickblox

I have been using Quickblox SDK for Android for quite a while. However, the new SDK library made some of my code not working. Specifically, I create list of locations. Then I try to search for nearby locations, providing current location and radius.

```
  getLocationsBuilder.setCurrentPosition(qbLocation.getLatitude(),
  qbLocation.getLongitude());

  getLocationsBuilder.setRadius(point.getLatitude(),
          point.getLongitude(), (float) 5.0);



    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(qbLocation.getLatitude(),
            qbLocation.getLongitude());
```

However, I get the result that format is incorrect.

> '{"errors":{"current_position":["should be in GeoPoint
>   format","should be set with radius"]}}'

Here is my whole code:

```
    Log.d(TAG,
            "update location is " + point.getLatitude() + " "
                    + point.getLongitude());

    QBLocationRequestBuilder getLocationsBuilder = new QBLocationRequestBuilder();
    getLocationsBuilder.setPage(1);
    getLocationsBuilder.setPerPage(100);
    getLocationsBuilder.setLastOnly();

    getLocationsBuilder.setCurrentPosition(qbLocation.getLatitude(), qbLocation.getLongitude());

    getLocationsBuilder.setRadius(point.getLatitude(),
    point.getLongitude(), (float) 5.0);

    int unixTime = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L - 1000);
    getLocationsBuilder.setMinCreatedAt(unixTime);

    // getLocationsBuilder.setSort(SortField.DISTANCE);

    QBLocations.getLocations(getLocationsBuilder, new QBEntityCallback<ArrayList<QBLocation>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBLocation> qbLocations, Bundle bundle) {
            ArrayList<String> card_ids = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (QBLocation location : qbLocations) {
                Log.d(TAG, "locations nearby : " + location);
                card_ids.add(location.getStatus()); // status is card_id
            }
            getCards(card_ids);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(List<String> strings) {

        }
    });
```

I can search for all locations, and get the ones which I want, but that is not so elegant as using SDK.

If I just replace Quickblox SDK with the earlier version it works fine.

Comment: Also, when I search just for all locations and there is only one result, the SDK crashes telling that QBCustomObject cannot be cast to QBEntityLimited

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was fixed in 1.2.4

http://quickblox.com/developers/Android#Framework_changelog:

which version do you use?

Comment: I think it works with SDK 1.2.4. But I want to use newest API and have already rewrote my program and QuickBlox calls to support new callbacks. Only locations do not work.